# R: Using toString on a list of objects

Tags: r

#### Question

How do I make `toString` output each element of a list the same way as `toString` outputs a single object?

#### Explanation

I have created a class an implemented the `to.character` method for it. It works fine when I use `as.character` or `toString` on one object. But if I use those functions on a list of objects I get an uninformative string, which seems to be the output from `deparse`.

#### Example code:

```
setClass("my.class",
    slots = c(value = "character"))

my.class <- function(value) {
  new("my.class", value = value)
}

setMethod("as.character", "my.class", function (x) {
  return(paste0('MyClass(',x@value,')'))
})

obj1 = my.class("val1")
obj2 = my.class("val2")

# desired: MyClass(val1)
# actual:  MyClass(val1)
message(toString(obj1))

# desired: MyClass(val1)
# actual:  <S4 object of class "my.class">
message(toString(list(obj1)))

# desired: MyClass(val1), MyClass(val2)
# actual:  <S4 object of class "my.class">, <S4 object of class "my.class">
message(toString(list(obj1, obj2)))

# FYI:
# outputs: <S4 object of class structure("my.class", package = ".GlobalEnv")>
message(deparse(obj1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `toString` is basically a wrapper to `paste()`. So the problem is how `paste(list(obj1, obj2))` runs compared to `paste(obj1, obj2)`. It seems when you pass a list like that, the internal `paste()` code runs a function called `coerceVector` which ultimately calls a `deparse` like function on each of the elements. A seimilar thing happens with S3 classes

```
paste(list(lm(1:10~rnorm(10)), lm(1:10~rnorm(10))))
```

What if you defined your own collection class? For example

```
setClass("my.classes",
    slots = c(values = "list"))

setMethod("as.character", "my.classes", function (x) {
  sapply(x@values, function(z) as(z, "character"))
})

my.classes <- function(...) {
  new("my.classes", values = list(...))
}

list1 <- my.classes(obj1, obj2)
toString(list1)
# [1] "MyClass(val1), MyClass(val2)"
```

Or maybe you could create a special `toString` method for lists? This would look like

```
toString.list <- function(x, ...) {
    paste(sapply(x, toString), collapse=", ")
}
```

then you would call

```
toString(list(obj1, obj2))
# [1] "MyClass(val1), MyClass(val2)"
```

The problem would be if any functions depended on the default behavior of `toString.default` for list objects so it seems a bit less safe, but certainly easier.

And let me clarify that i'm not S4 class expert, but I really can't see a way around the `paste()` problem after looking at the C code.

Comment: Perhaps `toString.list <- function(x,...){do.call(paste,c(x,sep=', '))}` would be more idiomatic

Comment: @mnel I'm having a hard time thinking of a case where they would be different. Do you have an example on hand?

Comment: They should be identical, but `do.call` is more "idiomatically" R-ish (perhaps)

Comment: Thanks. Defining toString.list worked fine – lets hope it does not have any unforeseen side effects. It is sad that there is no cleaner way to do it.